# k3s + MetalLB: metallb-controller Failed to allocate IP for "default/nginx": no available IPs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s, metallb

I created a k3s cluster and disabled the service loadbalancer & traefik.  I installed metallb via a manifest file.  Also, I created a ConfigMap for Metallb below named "config" with an address pool so I don't know why the metallb-controller is saying "no available ips".

```
ubuntu@mark:~$ k describe svc nginx
Name:                     nginx
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=nginx
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=nginx
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.29.17
IPs:                      10.43.29.17
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30584/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.4.4:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From                Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----                -------
  Warning  AllocationFailed  34s   metallb-controller  Failed to allocate IP for "default/nginx": no available IPs
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
      - name: default
    protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.136.206-192.168.136.209
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using the ConfigMap while in the [documentation](https://metallb.universe.tf/#backward-compatibility) it says that in newer versions you should not use it:

> Previous versions of MetalLB are configurable via a configmap.
> However, starting from the version v0.13.0, it will be possible to
> configure it only via CRs. A tool to convert old configmaps to CRs is
> provided as a container image under quay.io/metallb/configmaptocrs.

I was doing the same thing, I had an old repo, where I used the ConfigMap, so I decided to reuse it, but than I read the documentation and followed the instructions from the MetalLB [website](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

From [installation](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) I executed the following commands:

```
kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy

# see what changes would be made, returns nonzero returncode if different
kubectl get configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml | \
sed -e "s/strictARP: false/strictARP: true/" | \
kubectl diff -f - -n kube-system

# actually apply the changes, returns nonzero returncode on errors only
kubectl get configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml | \
sed -e "s/strictARP: false/strictARP: true/" | \
kubectl apply -f - -n kube-system

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.9/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml
```

, and then from the [configuration](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/) I choose the [Layer 2 Configuration](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration) setup. Add the code bellow in a file.yaml:

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250
```

, and then apply it using kubectl

```
kubectl apply -f file.yaml
```

After that every thing works well. I hope this answer would be helpful for those who used the old approach, correct me if I have misunderstood.

Comment: What do I do if I don't have a config map?
`kubectl get configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml`
Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "kube-proxy" not found

Comment: This worked for me, and got it out of pending, but now I have connection refused?

Answer (score 5):

Install the latest stable version:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.9/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml
```

Define an IPAddressPool

```
---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: nat
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
    - 192.168.136.206-192.168.136.209
---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: empty
  namespace: metallb-system
```

Comment: I also wanted to add, I realized since I was initializing this cluster and disabled flannel, traefik and a few other things in the arguments, I didn’t even realize I had no networking CNI configured.

Comment: For anyone else who lands here - I tried doing the Helm installation with *exactly* these parameters and it didn't work. I have no idea why but installing via the manifest did. Not sure if the Helm install is broken or I'm just missing something I can't seem to find